# coloring many lines

Tags: formatting, color

I would like to color several lines of text, each terminated by `\\`, but it seems that I have to insert a `\color` command for each line.
As I understand the `\\` terminates the TeX group, how can solve the problem?

I should specify that the lines are inside a `\author{}` command.

This is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\date{}

\author{\textbf{A. Author1}$^1$, \textbf{B. Author2}$^2$ and \textbf{C. Author3}$^3$\\
$^1$Line1\\
Line2\\
\color{blue}
$^2$ Line3\\
Line4\\
$^3$ Line5\\
Line6
}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Text of the abstract.
\end{abstract}


\section*{Introduction}
Text of the introduction.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. It matters how \author is defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: done.

Comment: Normally the \\ doesn’t end a group but `\author` internally uses a `{tabular}` and then \\ ends a cell; an a cell is a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be using the standard features of `\author`, you can change how `\@author` is typeset by `\maketitle` (actually, `\@maketitle`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em
  \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em
%%% removed lines
%      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
%        \@author
%      \end{tabular}\par}%
%%% end
%%% added lines
      \centering
        \@author
      \par}%
%%% end
    \vskip 1em
    {\large \@date}
  \end{center}
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\date{}

\author{\textbf{A. Author1}$^1$, \textbf{B. Author2}$^2$ and \textbf{C. Author3}$^3$\\[1ex]
$^1$Line1\\
Line2\\
\color{blue}
$^2$Line3\\
Line4\\
$^3$Line5\\
Line6
}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Text of the abstract.
\end{abstract}


\section*{Introduction}
Text of the introduction.
\end{document}
```

[image]